# Maximum Bipartite Matching C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, matching, bipartite

I'm solving a matching problem with two `vectors` of a `class`

```
class matching
{
public:
    int n;
    char match;
};
```

This is the algorithm I'm trying to implement:

```
int augment(vector<matching> &left, vector<matching> &right)
{
   while(there's no augmenting path)
     if(condition for matching)
        <augment>
  return "number of matching";
}
```

For the rough matching, if `left[i]` matches with `right[j]`, then `left[i].n = j`, `left[i].match ='M'` , `right[j].n = i` and `right[j].match = 'M'` and the unmatched ones have members `n = -1` and `match = 'U'`

While finding the augmenting paths, if one exists for another (i, j), then we change the member `match` of the one being unmatched from `'M'` to `'U'`  and its `n = -1`  and the two matched with the augmenting path have their members `match` changed to 'A' while we change their members `n` according to their indices.

I don't know if this is the right approach to solving this, this is my first attempt on  maximum matching and I've read a lot of articles and watched tutorials online and I can't get my 'code' to function appropriately.

I do not need a code, I can write my code. I just want to understand this algorithm step by step. If someone can give me an algorithm like the one I was trying above, I would appreciate it. Also, if I have been going the wrong direction since, please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if you are finding the augmenting paths correctly. I suggest the following approach.

1. Find an initial matching in a greedy way. To obtain this we travel through every vertex in the left side and greedily try to match it with some free (unmatched) vertex on the right side.
2. Try to find an augmenting path P in the graph. For this we need to do a          breadth-first search starting from all the free vertices on the left side and alternating through matched and unmatched edges in the search. (i.e. the second level contains all the right side vertices adjacent to level-1
          vertices, the third level contains all the left side vertices that are
          matched to level-2 vertices, the fourth level contains all the right side
          vertices adjacent to level-3 vertices etc). We stop the search when we
          visit a free vertex in any future level and compute the augmenting path P
          using the breadth-first search tree computed so far.
3. If we can find an augmenting path P in the previous step:  Change the matched and unmatched edges in P to unmatched and matched edges respectively and goto step 2.
4. Else: The resulting matching obtained is maximum.

This algorithm requires a breadth-first search for every augumentation and so it's worst-case complexity is `O(nm)`. Although [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft-Karp_algorithm) can perform multiple augmentations for each breadth-first search and has a better worst-case complexity, it
seems (from the Wikipedia article) that it isn't faster in practice.

Comment: Where I'm confused is that if an augmenting path exist already, can it be unmatched in order to find another augmenting path?

Comment: @F'OlaYinka: You don't ever have to do backtrack, which is what makes this algorithm clever. It can be proven (though not by me :-P) that a maximum-cardinality matching can always be found by repeatedly looking for and integrating an augmenting path until no more can be found.

Comment: What j_random_hacker said is correct! You can "greedily" keep finding augmenting paths using the above approach until you cannot find them any more. At this point you can prove that the matching M obtained is maximum. The proof isn't too difficult either. If there exists a bigger matching M', the "XOR" of M and M'  should contain an augmenting path, which should have been found in the BFS step of the algorithm. A contradiction.